# ASP.NET - Jquery load() not respecting web.config authorization

Tags: jquery, asp.net, load, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a asp.net intranet web app with Windows authentication mode and anonymous access enabled. In my web.config I have the following set for a 'Secure' sub-folder:

```
<location path="Secure">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The issue is if I hit a page in the Secure folder directly I am correctly validated or challenged for my credentials. However the way I am doing this is by using a JQuery dialog box to load() a page from the Secure folder. The page-behind code in the Secure folder is not executed (which is correct), but any static content is sent with a 200 status code. Here's the JS code:

```
$('#MyDivID_link').live('click', function (event) {
editDialog.load("Secure/MyEditPage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    $("#MyDivID_Win").html("You are not authorized to use this application or your web browser is not supported.<br><br>Please use Internet Explorer to edit content.");
  } else {
    $("#btnSubmit").show();
  }
}).dialog('open');
return false; });
```

This all works correctly except for the fact the load() status is 200, so the static content is returned and the load method thinks everything is fine.

Anyone know how I can configure my app to correctly check authentication on a load() and not return anything or is there another JQuery method that will work better? I do not want to set the 'Secure' sub-folder as a Virtual Directory with its own web.config (although this method does work) due to intranet restrictions.

Sort of confusing so let me know if I have to elaborate on anything. Thanks for any help.

Comment: it has nothing to do with jQuery, it looks like a sever configuration problem

Comment: Thanks Arun, I agree it's not a JQuery issue. It almost sounds like an IIS/.NET bug as this would allow people to see some content that their app is configured not to show anonymously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up managing this by wrapping the entire secure file's content in a div with the ID 'SecureContentWrapper' and set to runat="server". Then in the secure page's code-behind I check System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name against the allowed users and if the person doesn't have access permissions I overwrite the SecureContentWrapper div's InnerText to a permission's warning. It get's the job done and works with the JQuery UI dialog box perfectly.